# How can i display more than one array elements that satisfy a condition?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I display multiple values of an array to the console that match the condition (e.g: === "McDonalds")?

I only managed to display one item. But I don't know how i can display all the value of my array.

```
public products: product[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "McFlurry", price: 2, enseigne:"McDonalds" },
    { id: 2, name: "Potatoes", price: 3, enseigne:"McDonalds" },
    { id: 3, name: "BigMac", price: 4, enseigne:"KFC" },
    { id: 4, name: "Nuggets", price: 3, enseigne:"KFC" }
];


searchEnseigne(){
    let server = this.products.find(x => x.enseigne === "McDonalds");
    console.log(server);
}
```

Comment: How do you want to display them?  One line at a time in the console?  As a comma-delimited list?  Maybe please give us an idea of your expected output.

Comment: you want to check which all products are "McDonalds"?

Comment: I'm trying to display it in console actually like an array list

Comment: Shivaraj : yes exactly

Comment: @SteveDemeulemeester, please edit your question to say you want all array elements with enseigne of "McDonalds". Currently, you're just asking for all array items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

The `filter()` method creates a new array with **all elements** that pass the test. While The `find()` method returns the value of the **first element**

```
searchEnseigne(){
    let server = this.products.filter(x => x.enseigne === "McDonalds");
    console.log(server);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let server = this.products.filter(x => x.enseigne === "McDonalds");
 console.log(server);
```

Comment: If you look at the question, you have an incorrect answer, I read the comments and I know you are right, but you have to get OP to edit the question correct it and answer him.

Comment: @Aragorn: Thanks. I am not sure why people downvote when question itself is not clear, he is using console and I used the same. Could you please let me know what you want me to do?

Comment: Where did you get this: `if(product.enseigne  === "McDonalds")` requirement? Anyone looking at just the question think you are incorrect, hence downvote.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, in my case product is an interface so i can't use it in a for loop i guess

Comment: @Shivaraj I edited the question based on the comments, your answer looks good now, +1

Comment: @Aragorn: Thanks for that :) Atleast it is at zero rather than negative.